# executing a script with spaces in the path leading to it

Tags: r, shell, command-line

I'm trying to execute a R script which has spaces in the path leading to it. It fails with path not found error. My command looks like this..

```
Rscript ../A/B C/test.R
```

I've tried

```
Rscript "`../A/B C/test.R`"
Rscript "../A/B C/test.R"
```

Doesn't work. What's going wrong here?

Comment: Did you check that this _is_ the correct path?

Comment: +1 to @AndyClifton's comment, because that last version (`Rscript "../A/B C/test.R"`) should work just fine, if there's a runnable file there.

Comment: If you run Rscript --help you will see " 'file' may contain spaces but not shell metacharacters" , so I wonder if path expansion is supported.

Comment: Yup it is the correct path.

Comment: Post exact commands and exact error messages for those tests please. Specifically the last one.

Answer (score 1):

First let's try the obvious, escape the space:

```
Rscript "../A/B\ C/test.R"
```

If that doesn't work, `cd` inside the folder and try calling it from there:

```
cd A/B\ C/ && Rscript test.r
```

(Assuming you're in the parent folder)

If is still not working.. maybe is something inside the script.. What do you have in it?

R has problem sometimes managing spaces with single escape characters, so, if -let's say-, inside your script you have:

```
source("x.r")
```

And the FULL PATH of x.r has spaces in its name (like being in the same folder as the file in your example..), it can fail due to not finding the file called from inside r.

Then, change the paths INSIDE the script to have double escapes at the spaces

```
/A/B C/ -> /A/B\\ C/
```

And try again the previous options i posted.

Tell us what happens!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running your line of code from the Unix shell.

There may be an error in your directory name or file itself. As a test case, you may try the following:

```
Rscript "/directory/test A/rnorm.R"
```

rnorm.R being:

```
x <- rnorm(200, 10, 4)
print(x)
```

This basically should print the numbers to your Shell.